Is anyone using Nats Object Store in production?
We are using Nats in production since a while and recently there has been a case where the messageSize has exceeded 8MiB.
I tried extending the default message size in server-config to 10MiB, but it gave us a warning that it might lead to reduced performance.
Also this article recommended against using large message sizes and instead to use an ObjectStore.
We came across Nats Object Store and did some initial PoC, its working fine.
Even in version release, it seemed mature enough.
But wondered if someone is using Nats Object Store in production setup?
I tried running a local 3 node Nats cluster and running ticker every 100ms to add objects to bucket.
It worked fine until it hit the server resource limitation.
